# For each record, count records dated earlier in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, count

I have a table that contains a column `year`. I need, for each row, calculate the number of entries where the year is less than that in the row.

So that the output would look like:

> col1 | col2 | ... | year | number of entries prior to this year

I'm using PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `RANK()` function for this:

```
SELECT 
    col1, col2, ..., year,
    RANK() OVER (ORDER BY year) - 1
      AS number_of_entries_prior_to_this_year
FROM
    tableX ;
```

Tested in **[SQLFiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/48707/14)**

There is also a more complicated approach:

```
SELECT 
    col1, col2, year,
    COUNT(*) OVER (ORDER BY year) - COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY year)
      AS number_of_entries_prior_to_this_year
FROM
    tableX ;
```